# ubuntu /var file full and do not have read permissions

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I seem to have hosed myself, as I was running/learning some failing PHP/MySQL data scrape script and went off to bed.  I don't know if it looped or what exactly happened, but I came back and it showed disk almost full.  The analyzer said I had used almost 100G of a 100G drive on a /var directory. I try du and df-ah, but it will not show where the hog is. Says, "Permission denied." for many of the directories.

Clues:
1) gdm directory is listed as recent but won't let me look inside.
2) I was running an edit program called gksudo gedit, because I could not write to /var/www files for PHP.  It appears that in the ps window, a nautilus program is dormant.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I love ubuntu, but I'm pretty much a linux newbie. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have root permissions?

```
sudo bash
```

Then you can go in and look into what is going on.

```
cd /var
du -s *
```

Oh, and I hope I don't have to mention that you should not delete stuff that you didn't create yourself.  You might just delete something important.

You report that /var/log/apache seems "large".  I do NOT recommend simply deleting the files.  Instead, if you are very very sure that no-one will ever need to see any historical archives of the errors and accesses made, you can:

```
cd /var/log/apache
for f in *; do > $f; done
```

which will truncate the files.  This will make it less likely to cause problems due to non-existant files or bad permissions or required rotation signaling.  If you might need these files in the future, we could talk about using logrotate to try and save them.

Comment: Hi thank you, I've been tracing more and it appears that if I look under /var/log/apache2$ du it returns 99114776. Any idea if I can just rm it? more explicitly, rm /var/log/apache2$

Comment: Hi, after some more troubleshooting, I see...

Comment: @jrent: I edited the answer.  Take a look.

Comment: @Seth. Whew! Worked like a charm. Thank you! Also, the sudo bash privileges showed it was an error log. Do I need to undo the privileges (sudo bash)?  Thanks Again All.

Comment: @jrent: yes, type `exit`.  The `id` command should report your normal UID instead of 0.  Also remember to upvote useful answers and access whichever one was most helpful.

Comment: @Seth. Just to let you know, I didn't miss the upvote comment. I need 15 reps to use it.  Much appreciated again. If you are any indication of the caliber of helpers here, I'll be sure to be back often!

Comment: @jrent: It doesn't actually apply to me.  I've hit the 200/day upvote cap.  It was just a reminder as to the common practice since you appeared new.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem permissions require root access to read many of the directories in `/var`:

`ls -l /var`

```
...
drwx--x--x  3 root root  4096 2011-04-04 23:13 www
```

You just need root privileges to read them all:

```
sudo -s
cd /var/www
ls -l
```

Be careful running with a root shell. You can make a ton of mistakes really quickly, some might be difficult to undo. :)